Read with Java a file that contains text encoded as UTF-8 bytes with python
We need to process text at some files retrieved from a remote place. They are in UTF-8, but the main problem is that the files can have text in many languages, and they all have a single line in this format:
encoded_source_string = "b'\nHola,\n\nAqu\xc3\xad est\xc3\xa1 la informaci\xc3\xb3n de contacto que solicitaste:\n\n<table>[...more-text-data...]'";

Apparently this text is a UTF-8 encoding of a string in Python:
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#converting-to-bytes.
Non-ascii chars are changed to a byte representation of that char.
We need to decode back in Java this UTF-8 text before processing it. The text would be something like:
decoded_string = "\nHola,\n\nAquí está la información de contacto que solicitaste:\n\n<table>[...more-text-data...]";

So we are wondering if there is some build-in Java class or library to handle this format.
Or how could we decode it back?
Notes: We can't change how the files are generated, and we have to use Java in this process due to the stack currently in use.
I have tried several examples here in StackOverflow or in internet, but they use text encoded in Java's methods, not Python's, which create a very different output format. Using getBytes() and String(bytes, charset) does not work, they retrieve the same text without changes:
byte[] bytes = full_text.getBytes("UTF-8");
String decoded = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(decoded); // For example purposes

// Output:
// b'\nHola,\n\nAqu\xc3\xad est\xc3\xa1 la informaci\xc3\xb3n de contacto que solicitaste:\n\n<table>

I have tried also with AI chats, but no example has worked, all examples are different uses of getBytes() and String(), for example:
String decodedString = new String(utf8String.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

Thanks in advance for your comments.

Preprocess the files with a simple Python script (using eval()) to convert the data to proper UTF-8

Yea ... the "b\' ... " is a Python string literal syntax.  The best thing for understanding Python string literals is Python.  Java won't understand it unless you (or someone) implements a Python string literal parser in Java.  (We aren't going to do that for you, and you will have difficulty finding an existing library to do it ... IMO.)  So your best bet is to write some Python to convert those weird files into regular UTF-8 text files that Java can read.

If you want to have a go at writing a Python string literal parser in Java, the syntax is here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals.  (Describing how to write a parser in Java is far too broad a topic for a StackOverflow question.)

See how to use Jython (Python implemented in Java) eval() in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25666852/721855
